# Extract int between two different strings in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a list `files` of strings of the following format:

```
files = ['/misc/lmbraid17/bensch/u-net-3d/2dcellnet/2dcellnet_v6w4l1/2dcellnet_v6w4l1_snapshot_iter_418000.caffemodel.h5', 
'/misc/lmbraid17/bensch/u-net-3d/2dcellnet/2dcellnet_v6w4l1/2dcellnet_v6w4l1_snapshot_iter_502000.caffemodel.h5', ...]
```

I want to extract the `int` between `iter_` and `.caffemodel` and return a list of those ints.

After some research I came up with this solution that does the trick, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant/pythonic way to do it, possibly using a list comprehension?

```
li = []
for f in files:
   tmp = re.search('iter_[\d]+.caffemodel', f).group()
   li.append(int(re.search(r'\d+', tmp).group()))
```

Comment: You need to use a capturing group. `r'iter_(\d+)\.caffemodel'` and then access the value through `.group(1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to add another possible solution: join the file names together into one big string (looks like the all end with `h5`, so there is no danger of creating unwanted matches) and use `re.findall` on that:

```
import re
li = [int(d) for d in re.findall(r'iter_(\d+)\.caffemodel', ''.join(files))]
```

Comment: I like your solution... It is very readable (better than what I came up with ;))

Answer (score 2):

Use just:

```
li = []
for f in files:
   tmp = int(re.search('iter_(\d+)\.caffemodel', f).group(1))
   li.append(tmp)
```

If you put an expression into parenthesis it creates another group of matched expressions.

Comment: Why use lazy quantifier? It is redundant here. Use the greedy version, it is more efficient. And escape the dot. And use a raw string literal when you declare  a regex (just best practice).

Comment: Nice! I was able to generate the comprehension myself  `li = [int(re.search('iter_(\d+)\.caffemodel', f).group(1)) for f in files]` - I didn't know about the `( )` operation. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a [lookbehind assertion](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
regex = re.compile("(?<=iter_)\d+")

for f in files:
     number = regex.search(f).group(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with list comprehension, as you wished:

```
import re

re_model_id = re.compile(r'iter_(?P<model_id>\d+).caffemodel')
li = [int(re_model_id.search(f).group('model_id')) for f in files]
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a regex:

```
files = [
    '/misc/lmbraid17/bensch/u-net-3d/2dcellnet/2dcellnet_v6w4l1/2dcellnet_v6w4l1_snapshot_iter_418000.caffemodel.h5',
    '/misc/lmbraid17/bensch/u-net-3d/2dcellnet/2dcellnet_v6w4l1/2dcellnet_v6w4l1_snapshot_iter_502000.caffemodel.h5']

print([f.rsplit("_", 1)[1].split(".", 1)[0] for f in files])
['418000', '502000']
```

Or if you want to be more specific:

```
print([f.rsplit("iter_", 1)[1].split(".caffemodel", 1)[0] for f in files])
```

But your pattern seems to repeat so the first solution is probably sufficient.

You can also slice using find and rfind:

```
print( [f[f.find("iter_")+5: f.rfind("caffe")-1] for f in files])
['418000', '502000']
```